# GUI elements on different screens with same resolution but different size

Tags: java, swing, jframe, font-size, screen-size

I wrote a little Java program for a friend of mine, we have the same resolution ( 1920 * 1080 ), but his Screen in general is smaller than mine. To solve the problem I gave the GUI elements percentual coordinates, which works perfectly until I use fonts. The `Font` will be the same size, like mine which is like the code expects. The Bounds for a `JButton` for example says where to start where to end, but a font measured in points, so each inch has 72 points, a Font with 30 will always be half an inch. (Compare to the Images)

How can I fix this, I found nothing that could solve the problem in my eyes?

Image Before:
https://ibb.co/HXf0pt4

Image After:
https://ibb.co/1sbKyts

```java
public class DrawMenu extends JLabel{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        
        super.paintComponent(g);
        
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        int sw = (int) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth();
        int sh = (int) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight();
          
        g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, (int)Math.round(sw * 0.0078)));
        g.drawString("Termine die nächsten 0 bis 7 Tage", (int)Math.round(sw * 0.026), (int)Math.round(sh * 0.176));
        g.drawString("Termine die nächsten 8 bis 14 Tage", (int)Math.round(sw * 0.182), (int)Math.round(sh * 0.176));
        
        repaint();
    }
    
}
```

```java
public class Gui {

    static JFrame jfCounter, jfMenu, jfTask;
    static DrawCounter drawc;
    static DrawMenu drawm;
    static DrawTask drawt;
    static JButton kEnde, kNC, kA, kL, kEsc1, kEsc2, kEsc3, kEsc4, kEsc5, kLG, kLB, kAS, kEnter, kJFsw1, kJFsw2, kJFsw3,
            kJFsw4, ko[] = new JButton[6], kSettings, ktw, ktla, ktle, ktlb, ktnt;
    static JTextArea taAusgabe, taAusgabedw, taAusgabenw, taze, tabe, tati;
    static JFormattedTextField nfTag, nfMonat, nfJahr, nfTagA, nfMonatA, nfJahrA;
    static JTextField tfAnlass, tfkLBestimmt, tfAnlassA, tfAnlassAS, tfKonsole, tfKonsoleT, tfsettings[] = new JTextField[12], tftw,
            tftis, tftlbs, tftnct, tftnci;

    public Gui() {

        int sw = (int) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth();
        int sh = (int) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight();

        System.out.println(sw + " " + sh);

        // JFrame Settings
        jfCounter = new JFrame();
        jfCounter.setSize(sw, sh);
        jfCounter.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jfCounter.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jfCounter.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        jfCounter.setTitle("Tageszähler");

        jfMenu = new JFrame();
        jfMenu.setSize(sw, sh);
        jfMenu.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jfMenu.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jfMenu.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        jfMenu.setTitle("Menü");

        jfTask = new JFrame();
        jfTask.setSize(sw, sh);
        jfTask.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jfTask.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jfTask.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        jfTask.setTitle("Task");

        // JButtons
        Border bor = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1);
        Border boresc = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 3);

        kEnde = new JButton("Ende");
        kEnde.addActionListener(new ActionHandler());
        kEnde.setBounds((int) Math.round(sw * 0.026), (int) Math.round(sh * 0.509), (int) Math.round(sw * 0.195),
                (int) Math.round(sh * 0.028));
        kEnde.setBorder(bor);
        jfCounter.add(kEnde);

        kNC = new JButton("Neuer Counter");
        kNC.addActionListener(new ActionHandler());
        kNC.setBounds((int) Math.round(sw * 0.026), (int) Math.round(sh * 0.028), (int) Math.round(sw * 0.078),
                (int) Math.round(sh * 0.028));
        kNC.setBorder(bor);
        jfCounter.add(kNC);

        // JLabel / Draw
        drawc = new DrawCounter();
        drawc.setBounds(0, 0, sw, sh);
        drawc.setVisible(true);
        jfCounter.add(drawc);

        drawm = new DrawMenu();
        drawm.setBounds(0, 0, sw, sh);
        drawm.setVisible(true);
        jfMenu.add(drawm);

        drawt = new DrawTask();
        drawt.setBounds(0, 0, sw, sh);
        drawt.setVisible(true);
        jfTask.add(drawt);

        // JFrame Final Visible
        Gui.getJfMenu().setVisible(true);

    }
```

Comment: - As you want an ui that do not depend on Screen Geometry, do not use getScreenSize() (sw and sh, in your code) to compute your component's position.

Comment: Maybe you should use JPanel with a layout manager to help you to manage component's positions (it's the preferable way in swing)